# Complicated use of VPS to access internal system, using SSH tunnels

Tags: ssh, ports, minecraft

I am not exactly sure what the best solution would be for this problem, but

I have a VPS with 3 ips. I have a unix system behind a home router with no ports forwarded. I want to be able to access myVPSIP:25566 and get the data on the internal system.

myVPS ---> internal system

How do I go about doing this, I have tried reverse tunneling. If the minecraft server part causes confusion, here is an alternate example that will accomplish the same task.

I have a web server on a computer inside a home network. It cannot get incoming connections, so I purchased a VPS, and it has an IP. I wish to be able to access the web server via the VPS IP. I have tried reverse SSH Tunnel, but am unsure why it does not work.

here is the command I used

```
ssh -f -R 25566:127.0.0.1:25566 root@myvps -N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `GatewayPorts` configuration parameter of the SSH *server* to `yes`.  By default, it is `no`, which means that the server will not forward connections coming from another machine.  You may have to restart the SSH server (the software, not the hardware) after making this change for it to take effect.

Comment: is the command correct though?

Comment: Yes, the command appears correct.